# How to write a function output into .txt file?

Tags: function, python-2.7, random, output

I have to write a function that  produces random(parameter) integers i have to write random output of this funtion into .txt file. Also i have to find max and min integers from this function (write them into .txt too)

I cant find any tutorial about this subject. Want to use "a+" as writer.

Comment: what language do you want the function to be written in?  Add that as a tag..

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add . Python 2.7

Comment: Just looked through your question again - not clear at all. Is this homework?

Comment: Yeah Complete below function which get min, max and count parameters and produces random numbers between min, max values, and write them in a file.   
import random def createRandomNumberFile(min, max, count, outputFileName):  outputFile = open(outputFileName, “a+”)  for item in range(0, count):   randomNumber = random.randint(min,max)

Comment: Please put your code into the question. Otherwise it is unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please have a look online for tutorials on how to write to a file. There are loads of free resources online.

You have already done a lot of the work and only needed few more lines

```
import random 
def createRandomNumberFile(min, max, count, outputFileName):
    outputFile = open(outputFileName, 'a+')
    for item in range(0, count):
        randomNumber = random.randint(min,max) 
        outputFile.write(randomNumber)
    outputFile.close
```

Explanation - As you have assigned the file using the 'a+' mode (appending mode) to a variable (outputFile) you can simply use this variable to write to the file and then later close file (closing the file isn't always necessary but is good practice).

Hope that helps